# Django form populating dropdown from database values

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a django form and I need to populate the dropdown field from database

my form looks like

```
prod_cat = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=ProductCategory.objects.order_by('prod_cat', 'cat_desc').values_list('prod_cat', 'cat_desc').distinct())
```

when I run render it to my html dropdown it looks like this,

```
{'product_category':'Electronics','product':'Laptops'}
```

I want to display only the values, like this

```
Electronics Laptops
```

Comment: try with ProductCategory.objects.all()

Comment: It did not work

Comment: post your form view and models

Answer (score 0):

To display data in a custom way you have to subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance`:

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return '%s %s' %(obj.product_category, obj.product)
```

Use `MyModelChoiceField` instead of `ModelChoiceField`